# When does Naruto shonen jump end and shippuden begin

Tags: naruto

Just would like to know when or if the two series overlap and if so when should I watch Shippuden

Comment: unless i am misreading the question Naruto ends at the last episode of Naruto and Shippuden starts at the first episode of Shippuden, infact Wikipedia has 2 [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto_episodes) [list pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes). if there is any chronologically "overlap" in Shippuden it would be in the form of flashbacks or fillers which would not be best viewed by watching then out of order

Comment: Also, isn't shonen jump a magazine, and not a naruto series?

Comment: @NZKshatriya Shonen Jump is a magazine

Comment: As a manga, Naruto is just one whole series, they just separated it into two series in the anime.

Answer (score 1):

At age 12 or 13, Naruto goes with Jiraya to train and become stronger. That is when the Naruto series ends. 3 years later, Naruto returns to Konahakagure, and Shippuden starts.